# How to find a potentially unwanted app reported by Windows Security if it's not showing its name?

Tags: google-chrome, security, windows-11, windows-defender

### background

I noticed recently how my laptop is running slower. Poor responsiveness while typing. Google Chrome and System (ntoskrnl.exe) are the 2 processes that load the CPU the most. I've already tried to reset my browser settings. Also, I tried to execute quick scans using Kaspersky antivirus and Windows Defender. They found 0 threats.

[image]

### story

I navigated to Windows Security (Defender) and noticed this: *"Potentially unwanted app found. Your device may perform poorly."*

[image: Windows Defender - App & browser control]

When I click the Review button, I'm redirected to this empty Protection history screen:

[image: Windows Defender - Protection history]

I'm puzzled.

### question

How to find this potentially unwanted app reported by Windows Security if it's not showing its name? Any workarounds?

Maybe it has something to do with the laptop's poor performance issue. I'm concerned that if I simply dismiss this warning I will never find out why it was triggered.

Comment: Look in *Settings > Update & Security > Windows Security > Virus & threat protection > Protection history*, where you might find this information.

Comment: @harrymc 1. Instead of *Update & Security* I have *Privacy & Security*. 2. By following this path I get to the same empty screen that I've demonstrated in my screenshot.

Comment: This is abnormal. My guess is that your computer is infected by a virus that tries to eradicate all traces. If the virus cannot be eradicated, a reinstall of Windows with reformat would be required.